# How can I use $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS

Tags: bash, nautilus

I wort a bash script it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
D=`zenity --entry --entry-text='Folder'`
pattern1=`zenity --entry --entry-text='replace'`
pattern2=`zenity --entry --entry-text='by'`
cd "$D"
rename "s/$pattern1/$pattern2/g" *
zenity --info --text="Done"
```

it works very well.
I add it to nautilus scrips folder (~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts),
and I make some changes :

```
#!/bin/bash
pattern1=`zenity --entry --entry-text='replace'`
if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]
then
    exit
fi
pattern2=`zenity --entry --entry-text='by'`
if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]
then
    exit
fi
rename "s/$pattern1/$pattern2/g" \'$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS\'
zenity --info --text="Done"
```

but it does not work.
I hope that I find some help
thanks in advance.

Comment: the question is in the title:How can I use
$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
 I tried like you can see in the script but it does not work
sorry, you don't like this sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved,by two ways.
the first one:

using a for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
pattern1=`zenity --entry --entry-text='replace'`
if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]
then
    exit
fi
pattern2=`zenity --entry --entry-text='by'`
if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]
then
   exit
fi
for file in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
   do
     rename "s/$motif1/$motif2/g" "$file"
done
zenity --info --text="Done"
```

the second :
using a while loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
pattern1=`zenity --entry --entry-text='replace'`
if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]
then
    exit
fi
pattern2=`zenity --entry --entry-text='by'`
if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]
then
   exit
fi
echo $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS | while read 'file'
do
  rename "s/$motif1/$motif2/g" "$file"
done
zenity --info --text="Done"
```

the question now is why I have to do that 
and the answer is because $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS is a sequence
even if one file is selected we will find in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS the file selected path and a separator character
you can see that by using this commande:(add it to the script)

```
zenity --entry --entry-text="$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
```

I hope that this can be usefull for someone
[Inspired by that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243105/nautilus-scripts-nautilus-script-selected-file-paths-have-problems-with-spac)